# linking issue - trying to build a library and use another archive with it

Tags: c++, linker

Is it possible to build a library that uses another, already compiled library?

I have some make files that are used to normally build an executable. When making the executable, I use -L ../include/lib1.a to include the original library.

Now, I am building a separate program that is calling the classes from the executable, which was never built into a library, just compiled to the executable with a link like

```
${CPP} -c ${INC} ${CFLAGS} MyFile.cpp ${OBJ} ${LIB2} -lm
```

Where LIB2 includes the reference to lib1.a

Now I want to access the class MyFile.cpp directly, and when I build it to its own library lib2.a, and try to call it from the new program, I get a bunch of errors that the classes it references are missing. This is in spite of the fact that when building the new program I am linking in both lib1.a and lib2.a

Comment: Could you show your `make -n`? Guessing the variable substitutions is tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Should:

```
-L../include/lib1.a
```

not be:

```
-L../include -llib1
```

I.e. -L denotes the library search path and -l the archive name?

Comment: Good point. Also, isn't it kinda odd to be putting binary library files in an "include" directory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do it. It would be helpful to see the exact errors you are getting.

If you compile your sources into a library and supply the libraries they use on the command line, the compiler is liable to put the other library(s) **into** your new one. If that happens, and then someone tries to build a program against your library and those others, they will get a whole mess of "doubly-defined symbol" errors.

Comment: if two or more libraries define a symbol only one of them will be used (unless the other(s) are pulled in by other symbols). The one that will be used is that of the first library by the order in which they are specified. The above technique will not generate errors along with the original libraries as long as the new library is specified first.

Answer (score 0):

When you build lib2.a it will not contain the objects files contained in lib1.a.

Your final executable has to link in both of them.